# custom border around camera screen

Tags: xamarin.android

Use this code to draw an custom border  for the camera.

It works well on versions  above 5
It does not work on less than 4.2 or 4.4 .

I want to modify the file to work on all versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:width="220dp" android:height="220dp" android:viewportHeight="230.0" android:viewportWidth="230.0">
 <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
     android:pathData="M165,5C178.2,5 198.2,5 225,5L225,30.79L225,65"
     android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
 <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
     android:pathData="M5,65C5,51.8 5,31.8 5,5L30.79,5L65,5"
     android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
 <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
     android:pathData="M165,225C178.2,225 198.2,225 225,225L225,199.21L225,165"
     android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
 <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
     android:pathData="M5,165C5,178.2 5,198.2 5,225L30.79,225L65,225"
     android:strokeColor="@color/qr_code_reader_square" android:strokeWidth="10"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could support older versions with the Android support library, which provides the **VectorDrawableCompat** and **AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat** classes.

Refer to [Vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources)

in Xamarin.Android,you could install the nuget **VectorCompat**.